# Build a dynamic, typesafe queries

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two entities one is Event and another is User. User can like events, so it has a list of liked events (which is recorded in a joint table). I want to build a typesafe queries using JPA 2.0 to count how many people like an event given the event id. Could anyone help me with it? Thank you.

Below is the codes for the entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long eventId;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 200)
    protected String title;

        //getter and setter....
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "login", length = 64)
    protected String login;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_events",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "login")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")})
    protected List<Event> events;

    //getter and setters...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query is basically going to be static with the parameter being the event id, I would create a [@NamedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html), then use the [entity manager to create](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) a [TypedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html).  Since you are looking for the count, the type will likely be a Long.

The query could be something like `select count(u) from User u where :event member of u.events` assuming you have the event, not just the id.

If you have something against NamedQuery you could use the Criteria API to do the same, but where this query is so static I don't see much point in doing that.

Comment: Could you please give more details? You talked about use entity manager to create a TypedQuery, do you mean a JPQL query? But it is not type safed. What I want is to use Criteria API provide by JPA 2.0.

Comment: But I do want to use Criteria API to be consistent with my other codes. So could you please show me a sample code? Thanks.

Comment: The bottom half of this page http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select talks all about how to create a Criteria query.  You will just need to convert the query I gave above (or one of your making like it) into a criteria query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I convert the query you gave me to criteria query.